# Box2d: have sprite follow sprite

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

I just recently start to learn box2d, I am making a tiny wing clone. and i am trying to make a sprite follow another sprite, and eventually catch up.

since box2d is a whole new api to me, I do not know where to start.
The way I am thinking of is storing the leader sprite position into a cgpoint array and setting it to the other sprite, but since its box2d, and it goes up and down hills. I dont know if the animations are smooth enough

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these Tutorial

[Tiny wings tutorial Part-1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3888/how-to-create-a-game-like-tiny-wings-part-1)

[Tiny Wings tutorial Part-2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3913/how-to-create-a-game-like-tiny-wings-part-2)

You can find the project on Github here:
[Tiny-wings Clone github link](https://github.com/haqu/tiny-wings)

Comment: i already seem both of those, but it is a good link. I have posted my answer already

Answer (score 0):

My code is base of that, and I figured it out.
heres my code for now

```
- (void)makeNinjaFollow {
  if (posCounter >= 200) 
    posCounter = 0;

  pandaPositions[posCounter] = _panda.position;
  _enemy.position = pandaPositions[posCounter - 20];

}
```